# C# Adding an array of dynamic objects into a List of dynamic objects

Tags: c#

So i have an object of ojects like so

```
    [["value1","value2","value3"]]
```

and my goal is to access these objects, and modify them, then return it to a new list containing the existing objects.

Here's what I've tried

```cs
    List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach(var i in objects)
    {
       List<dynamic> innerData = new List<dynamic>();
       foreach(var j in i)
       {
           innerData.Add(j + " NEW");
       }
       data.AddRange(innerData);
    }
```

the output isn't the same. It will return the following

```
    [["value1 NEW"], ["value2 NEW"],["value3 NEW"]]
```

It returns a new list, but instead of having one object with three values inside the list, it returns three objects with one value inside the list.

My goal is to have the same output format as the input format. Like so

```
    [["value1 NEW","value2 NEW", "value3 NEW"]]
```

Comment: Can't you just add them straight to the `data` list in your inner loop? Instead of adding them to a second list, and adding the list to the full list.

Comment: The format will not be the same. It will add multiple each of them independently. My goal is to add the entire group, containing the independent values

Comment: You did an `AddRange`. Try doing `Add`. I'm not sure if the compiler will allow that but what you did was basically add *each item* in the internal collection to the main collection. And what you want is add it as a collection.

Comment: What is `objects` instantiated with?

Comment: tic Objects is declared as List<dynamic> objects

Comment: @Thatguy use Add instead of AddRange.

Comment: Why do you have double square brackets around the expected results? What is that supposed to represent? FYI, an array is declared like: `string[] foo = new [] { "first", "second", "third" };`. Just trying to understand your syntax.

Comment: As @iSR5 said; if you want the double-square brackets then `Add` will achieve that

Comment: @iSR5 Did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using dynamic in the first place

Comment: @johnny5 the application being used (Kofax) requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments you need to use [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add) instead of [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange). `AddRange` adds each element of a list as a new element in the outer list and what you want is add the inner list as one element of the outer list.

The fixed code then looks like this:

```
List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
foreach(var i in objects)
{
    List<dynamic> innerData = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach(var j in i)
    {
        innerData.Add(j + " NEW");
    }
    data.Add(innerData);
}
```